# Tesseract and OCRopus

Tags: ocr

1. I was wondering what relations are between Tesseract and OCRopus?

   Is OCRopus a wrapper of Tesseract? Or are they now developing
   independently?
2. What are some advantages of one over the other?

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only intra-relationship between the two OCR tools was that prior to v0.4 of OCRopus, it used Tesseract as its character recognition tool via a plugin.

[OCRopus](http://code.google.com/p/ocropus/) has since replaced [Tesseract](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/) with its own engine primarily for future capabilities such as additional languages and handwriting tools.  However you still have the option of using Tesseract.

OCRopus is a full GUI based application.

Tesseract itself is a backend-engine - various front-end GUIs use Tesseracts' capabilities.  Thus you cannot directly compare the two.

The last major release of OCRopus was March 2010 - but it does have [major plans](http://code.google.com/p/ocropus/wiki/ReleaseNotes) for a future v0.5.

In terms of activity - Google are reporting high developer activity for Tesseract whereas OCRopus is slower with a medium rating.

Comment: Thanks! Do you mean  OCRopus is now also a backend engine, and therefore the two has become comparable?

Comment: OCRopus now has its own backend engine - but the whole GUI + engine is called OCRopus.  Tesseract is just a backend engine.

Comment: Thanks! How can I find out "Google are reporting high developer activity for Tesseract whereas OCRopus is slower with a medium rating"?

Comment: click on the links in my reply - look top left.  Activity is reported there.